# Android what grid layout to use

Tags: android, xaml

[image]
in XAML, I can do this easily

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinition>

    <!--#region canvas -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
    </Grid>
    <!--#endregion -->

    <!--#region parameters -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
    </Grid>
    <!--#endregion -->
</Grid>
```

I am moving to Android development for the first time and I am not sure which type of "widget" to use to have the same grid layout behavior as above (Screenshot)

How do I make a grid that has the same layout behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to achieve this is to use LinearLayout and assign weights 1 and 0 to the two corresponding elements, and heights "0dp" and "wrap_content" correspondingly:

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    ...
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    ...
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0">
    ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

(Where `RelativeLayout`s need to be replaced with your elements).

The way `layout_height` and `layout_weight` work is the following: the elements within the `LinearLayout` generally will have heights proportional to their weights. So, for example, if two elements have weights 1 and 2, the second one will be twice as tall as the first one.

However, the element will not be smaller than its `layout_height`.

Now, with these two things in mind, the XML above effectively says "I want the first element to be infinitely bigger than the second, but the second cannot be shorter than what is needed to enclose its child elements", which is exactly what you want.

You might also come across some articles on the web using `layout_height="fill_parent"`. It will also work, but it's a deprecated solution, and the solution with `layout_weight`s should be generally preferred.

Comment: @jaysonragasa, if the answer works, you should accept it :)